# Should I use compound index when I use both where and order by id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 8.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id
```

The related columns and index statuses are:

- `id`: Primary Key (Indexed)
- `status`: Indexed

My question is:

Both `id` and `status` are indexed. Do I still need a separate compound index (status, id)?

Answer (score 0):

Only one index per `SELECT` can be used. So having different indexes on different columns won't help (that much) when the different columns are all involved in one `SELECT`.

In your case you may want to try an index on `users (status, id)`. Use `EXPLAIN` to check if it gets picked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InnoDB, the secondary index on `status` implicitly has the primary key appended anyway. It's as if you had an index on `(status, id)`.

So you'd select rows with the given value of `status=1`, and then InnoDB would read those rows in index order, and that means they would be returned in order by `id`. Since this matches your `ORDER BY` clause, the optimizer knows it can skip doing any work to sort the result.

You can use `EXPLAIN` to confirm this. What you'll look for is that the *absence* of "Using filesort" in the extra field of the EXPLAIN report.